# Python using row index as variable input to equation within numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can't figure out how to in python without creating a for loop. I'm hoping you can teach me the simpler way.

I trimmed the relevant stuff. I'm doing a polyfit and then want to use these a and b coefficients, coeff[0:1], to update an array and solve the relevant y's like: y = ax + b

I can brute force it and included two methods here, but they're both clunky.

```
import numpy as np

raw = [0, 3, 6, 8, 11, 15] 

coeff = np.polyfit(np.arange(0, len(raw)), raw[:], 1) #fits slope of values in raw

fit = np.zeros(shape=(len(raw), 2))

fit[:,0] = np.arange(0,fit.shape[0]) # this creates an index so I can use the row index as the "x" variable


fit[:,1] = fit[:,0]*coeff[0] + fit[:,0]*coeff[1] # calculating y = ax * b in column [1]


## Alternate method with the for loop

for_fit = np.zeros(len(raw))

for i in range(0,len(raw)) :
    for_fit[i] = i*coeff[0] + i*coeff[1]
```

Comment: Show an MCVE. It's good that you trimmed the cruft, but you need to show a runnable example with representative inputs and corresponding outputs.

Comment: I fixed the markdown in two different ways: indent by four spaces, or surround with triple backticks. If you indent by four, the previous line must be a blank line.

Comment: For tips on MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. I replaced it with code that executes and clearer markup.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it a little bit cleaner. The main issue I saw is that you did not use the formula `y = ax+b` but rather `y=ax+bx`.

```py
import numpy as np

raw = [0, 3, 6, 8, 11, 15]
x = np.arange(0, len(raw))

coeff = np.polyfit(x, raw[:], 1)
y = x*coeff[0] + coeff[1]
```

To visualise the result we can use:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, raw, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
```

[image: linear regression]

---

#EDIT
Are you looking for something like this?

```py
y_arr = np.empty((10, len(x)))

for i in range(10):
   ...
   y_arr[i] = y
```

Comment: the y = ax + bx thing was a typo. I'm actually fitting 3rd order shapes. But I didn't realize I could just multiply the np array by integers that way. It's exactly what I was looking for.  I was trying to implement that but clearly did something wrong because it wasn't working. Thanks.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This does clean up the code, but isn't putting the result directly into a column of an existing array. I can create a temp array and then column_stack or some such, but it's not quite what I was hoping for.